# How to enable \pause on beamer slides by default?

Tags: beamer, pause

How to enable `\pause` on beamer slides by default?

By this I mean, every `enumerate` or `itemise` on every slide needs to have pause between its items.

The current workaround I have is to define a new command `\myitem` to be `\item\pause`, i.e., `\newcommand{\myitem}{\item\pause}`. But is there a builtin method?

Comment: This is already the case for lists. If you want it for something different, there should at least be some indication that *you* provide to tell TeX where to `\pause`. Could you provide an example of what you're after exactly?

Comment: @Werner Sure about that? With `\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
a
\item
b
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}` I get the whole list in one.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Hmmm, I may have been dreaming...

Comment: Quite apart from the technical issues _do not do this_. Using a 'reveal each line' list-based approach for _every_ slide is a good sign the slides need rethinking as they won't be helpful to the audience.

Comment: On a technical basis, you can make each list reveal item-by-item using `\begin{itemize}[<+->]`.

Comment: @Werner Are you sure you don't have `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` somewhere in your preamble or config file or whatever?

Answer (score 4):

I used to do this and then cancel the effect for slides where I didn't want it. However, I eventually figured out that undoing the effect involved more specifications than enabling the effect where I wanted it. However, you can do it if you wish by adding a default specification in the preamble.

```
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
```

for the lists you *really* want to appear item by item.

Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I absolutely agree with Joseph, that you should not do that!

But to actually answer your question: You could just redefine the item command.

```
\let\itemold\item
\renewcommand{\item}{\itemold\pause}
```

This way you do not need to use a custom `\myitem` command in your frames.

Comment: Using the show/don't show specification (e.g. `<+->` is "from here on") is much more flexible. E.g.in emacs AucTeX puts that by default.